# Validating a SelectList in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, not even sure if I am on the right track.  I have a view model and I create a drop down list from it.  Here is my view model:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
   {
      public Application Application  { get; private set; }
      public SelectList AccountTypes { get; private set; }

      public ApplicationViewModel(Application application, IEnumerable<AccountType> accountTypes)
      {
         Application = application;
         AccountTypes = new SelectList(accountTypes, "AccountTypeID", "AccountTypeName", application.AccountTypeID);
      }
   }
```

Here is my Create (get) action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
      {
         var viewModel = new ApplicationViewModel(new Application(), db.AccountTypes);

         return View(viewModel);
      }
```

And my view code:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(???, Model.AccountTypes, "-- Select --") %>
               <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(???) %>
```

In the code above, I'm not exactly sure what must come in ???  The initial value is "-- Select --".  If the user clicks on the submit button and the dropdown's value is still "-- Select --" then it must display a message.

I am also using EF4.  Please can someone advise as to what to do.  Code samples would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your View is strongly typed ie:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Model.NameSpace.ApplicationViewModel>"
```

Then the ??? in your view code should be a lambda expression referring to the items in your ViewModel. (I assume your ViewModel's ***Application*** object has a property that is going to be assigned a value based on the drop down list?)

I've assumed your application object has an AccountType property, For example:

??? should be something like:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Application.AccountType, Model.AccountTypes) %>
```

The value from the drop down list will populate the AccountType property on your Application model and will be populated with the AccountTypes from your ViewModel.

Hope this helps.

-- EDIT --

On your Application model, use the namespace:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Above your AccountTypes property, add

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Account Type Required")]
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes it is a strongly typed view.  It populates correctly your way, but I'm not getting the Html.ValidationMessageFor to trigger if nothing was selected.  I tried Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Application.AccountType) but it is not working.

Comment: Not sure if I can ask this here, when I click on submit then my Application does not have the AccountType or AccountTypeID. Here is my Create action: public ActionResult Create(Application application). How does this get set?